# Average score of a batsman's innings

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A batsman's runs just before the last match of the season, adds up to $750.$  In his last $2$ innings, he scores only $6$ runs, and his average drops by $2.$ Find his final average of the season.

$\sum x_{n-1}=750, x_{n-1}+x_{n}=6, \frac{\sum x_n}{n}=\frac{\sum x_{n-2}}{n-2}-2.$ That means I've net $4$ variables ($\sum x_{n-2}, x_{n-1}, x_n, n$) and only $3$ equations. So I am unable to solve it.

But the answer is given as $28$ runs.

Is there a way to solve this question? If not, then is the statement wrong? If yes, then how can we correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve set it up wrong, I’m afraid, because you’re not being careful enough with your indices. Let $n$ be the number of innings that he batted before the last match, and for $k=1,\ldots,n+2$ let $x_k$ be his score in the $k$-th innings. Then $\sum_{k=1}^nx_k=750$, more or less as you had it, and his total for the $n+2$ innings including those of the last match is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+2}x_k=750+6=756\;.$$

His batting average before the last match was $\frac{750}n$, and his batting average at the end of the season is

$$\frac{756}{n+2}=\frac{750}n-2\;.$$

That’s a single equation in the unknown $n$, which you can solve, and once you have $n$, you can find his average.

Comment: So the average of all innings is different from the average of all matches. Is it always so? I am not able to imagine it.

Comment: @Ramit: A batsman’s average is normally calculated per innings, because the number of innings in a match varies. In one-day cricket there’s only one innings per side; in Test and county cricket there are nominally two, but the second innings may not actually be played.

Comment: In the question, I couldn't guess that the last 2 innings belong to the last match. I should have guessed. But in any case, the question is not very clear. But I guess it was not an issue for you. You solved it in such a sure way.

Comment: @Ramit: Sorry: I spoke of them as belonging to his last match, because I was thinking of first-class cricket, but they could just as well have come from two separate matches. It doesn’t change the actual computation.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, but it's right there in the question ("just before the last match"). If you don't happen to know that a match has (or can have) two innings, you're stumped!

Comment: @Tony: Or possibly caught out. (**Was** *stumped* a deliberate pun?)

Comment: @Brian: It wrote itself...

Comment: @Tony: :-) Living in a part of the world where cricket is almost unknown, I wasn’t sure.